# UISearchBar hides view in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

When I initiate a search on UISearchBar which is a child off a UITableView, any other view except the UITableView becomes hidden. This issue only happens on iOS 7. And I dont have any specific code which hides the other views.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To come to the solution I first had to figure out the issue.

When text is input into the UISearchBar, it creates a UITableView which sits on top of the parent view.
To show the hidden parent view, the UITableView created must be offset and re sized to fit within a smaller area.

```
(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// The tableView the search tableView replaces
CGRect f = self.mainTableView.frame;
CGRect s = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
CGRect updatedFrame = CGRectMake(f.origin.x,
                             f.origin.y + s.size.height,
                             f.size.width,
                             f.size.height - s.size.height);
tableView.frame = updatedFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the viewDidLoad for the popover `UIViewController`:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: I gave that a try but im still seeing the same result. but thanks for the response, even though you are an eagles fan... Lets go cowboys!!